# docker pull in unit files only works at first start, gets ignored later on

Tags: coreos

I have a unit, running the "latest" tag of a docker image. The latest image is fetched by the "docker pull" command from the unit file at first start.

But at any subsequent (re)starts, the "docker pull" command doesn't seem to get executed, since any new image-revisions tagged with "latest" are not getting pulled.

Running the "docker pull ..." on the command line works as expected.

My service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
KillMode=none
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill foo
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm foo
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker login -e foo@example.com -u bla -p xxxxx https://myregistry.example.com && /usr/bin/docker pull myregistry.example.com/foo
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name foo myregistry.example.com/foo
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop foo

[X-Fleet]
Global=true
```

Is this behaviour intended? Is a workaround possible for this?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: Running CoreOS 557.2.0, docker 1.4.1 and fleetd 0.9.0

Comment: Your `docker pull` command is linked to the success of the `docker login` command via `&&`.  Does `docker login` return an error if you are already logged in?

Comment: No, says "Login Succeeded". But no error code.

Comment: systemctl says  (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) about the command

Comment: Any errors (or diagnostics) in (a) the journal for this unit (journal -u ...) or in the docker daemon log?

Comment: Hmm, you seem probably right. When removing "docker login ...  ||" everything works a expected at every restart. Assuming .dockercfg already exists with the credentials....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1 - use multiple ExecStartPre

I'm not sure you can use shell-style `&&` in an `ExecStartPre` section.

So one simple approach is just to break it up

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker login -e foo@example.com -u bla -p xxxxx https://myregistry.example.com 
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull myregistry.example.com/foo
```

#### Option 2 - install .dockercfg credentials via cloud-config

If you'd rather not embed credentials in unit files, you can have your CoreOS cloud-config write the credentials with a section like this

```
write_files:
  - path: /home/core/.dockercfg
    owner: core:core
    permissions: 0644
    content: |
      {"https://myregistry.example.com:5000":{"auth":"Y2FudGJlbGlldmU6eW91ZGVjb2RlZHRoaXM=","email":"user@example.com"}}
```

The auth value is a base64 username:password combo, which you can create or just grab a working .dockercfg file.

So, now your CoreOS machines will start up with the credentials they need, there's one more thing you need to do -  make sure the units that need to login to your registry run as the core user:

```
[Service]
User=core
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull myregistry.example.com/foo
```

#### Option 3 - use an actual shell

If you want to do shell-like things, you can always just start a shell and have it execute what you need

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/docker login -e foo@example.com -u bla -p xxxxx https://myregistry.example.com && /usr/bin/docker pull myregistry.example.com/foo'
```

Comment: Thanks!

As you mentioned on IRC, one can also put an ExecStartPre this way, if chaining is required:

`ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/docker login -e foo@example.com -u bla -p xxxxx https://myregistry.example.com && /usr/bin/docker pull myregistry.example.com/foo'`

Comment: Yes, I'll add that to the answer for completeness